# javascript confirm box issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, email

I have a email functionality my requirement was when user click on email button, user should confirm first that he is sure that he wants to send an email. To do this I have used javascript confirm box to ask user for confirmation before executing my server site code when send email.

Everything works fine on production but I few days before one of our user reported issue that when he clicks on email button he gets confirmation, He clicks on OK but still email was not send.

My suspect is, The javascript confirm box is not returning true value even though user clicks on "OK" button.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any exceptions, highly unlikely that the functionality would stop working on one fine day, any other changes you missed ?

Answer (score 1):

best way to check it is by storing the confirm value to a variable and alert it.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced simillar issue on my asp.net site. The fix I found was to write the confirm dialog js code in the button's tag itself (onClick=return confirm('...');), instead of writing a separate function and calling it in onClick. The solution is strange but it worked. May work for you!

Answer (score 0):

You may want place your javascript in *OnClientClick* attribute of your Button :

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btConfirmEmail" Text="Send" OnClientClick="return(confirm('Are you sure ?'))"/>
```

hope this will help